# How to display row data in a form when edit button is clicked (angular 8)

Tags: angular

I want row data to show in form fields when I clicked edit button on a particular table row, I have just one(1) component and both my table and the form is inside same component.html. How can I get it work?

See my code sample below:

**component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let myCar of cars$ | paginate: { itemsPerPage: count, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
            <td>{{ (p - 1) * count + i + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{myCar.name}}</td>
            <td>{{myCar.price}}</td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>Edit
                </button></td>
</tr>
<div class="col-sm-12">
        <form formGroup="editForm" autocomplete="off">
            <h4 align="center">
                <strong>Edit Car</strong>
            </h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Price:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="price">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></i>Save
            </button>
        </form>
</div>
```

**service.ts**

```
....
// requesting data via http
getCars() {
   return this.http.get<Cam[]>(this.carsUrl);
}
```

**component.ts**

```
// imports
......
editForm: FormGroup;

constructor(...){...}

ngOnInit() {
   carList();
   carEditInit();
}
carList() {
   return this.carService.getCars()
     .subscribe(data => {
        this.cars$ = data;
   });
}

// I just initialised the form fields
carEditInit() {
   this.editForm = this.fb.group({
     name: [''],
     price: ['']
   )};
}
```

How can I get these codes work, or what additions in the .ts file so that after clicking the "Edit" button, data are sent to the form fields. **I have both *ngFor table and form inside same component.html**

Thanks

Comment: can u make ur issue here ?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dxiv4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-basic.ts

Comment: @rajhim is there anything you need more info on as regards my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign (click) event to a function and pass it your myCar Object for the row where edit button is clicked

```
<tr *ngFor="let myCar of cars$ | paginate: { itemsPerPage: count, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
            <td>{{ (p - 1) * count + i + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{myCar.name}}</td>
            <td>{{myCar.price}}</td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="fillForm(myCar)">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>Edit
                </button></td>
</tr>
```

In .ts file, define the function and set your form fields using setValue():

```
fillForm(myCar)
{
   this.editForm.controls.name.setValue(myCar.name);
   // ... Do the same for rest of your form fields

  this.editForm.updateValueAndValidity(); //Update the values for all fields
}
```

Comment: I got this error in console: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined". But in "debugContext_" > elValue > oldValue > {.. I could see the row data here.....}. The data does not append to form. Any idea on why?

Comment: In your html template, you are not binding formGroup , use [formGroup]="editForm" to bind it to editForm defined in component

Comment: why not use patchValue or setValue: `this.editForm.setValue(myCar)`?

Comment: It is a Reactive form. You need to specify which control value you are updating.